# How to automatically convert a LaTeX math-mode equation into Python / numpy code?

Tags: math-mode, code, python, pythontex, convert

Mathpix converts scanned formulas into LaTeX math code. Is there a similar tool that automatically converts scanned formulas or LaTeX math-mode equations (code) into python and numpy code?

Answer (score 4):

[latex2sympy](https://github.com/augustt198/latex2sympy) might be what you are looking for.

Well, it does sympy, but from there it's easier to go to python and numpy, with the **lambdify** command, I think.